# Is a Torricellian vacuum a perfect vaccum(devoid of any kind of matter)?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, matter

Is a Torricellian vacuum as such in a mercury barometer a perfect vacuum i.e. is it devoid of any kind of matter? If not , then what does it contain and why?

As a 9th grade student , it is mentioned in our school's physics book - Concise physics class 9 - that a Torricellian vacuum is perfect. I disagreed with that statement as I knew a perfect vacuum couldn't be achieved. I even had a debate regarding this with our teacher but he insisted that we 'consider' it to be a perfect vacuum yet he was unclear on the reason why.

Comment: The vapor pressure of mercury at room temp is about 160 mPa, or 23 millionths of a psi. So roughly on millionth of an atmosphere. I’d say for most applications it is close enough to consider it “perfect”.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Jon Custer's comment, because the vapor pressure of the Mercury is limiting,  but it is good to provide some additional context. The vapor pressure of mercury is 0.0017 Torr at 25 °C. (one atmosphere is 760 mm of Hg or 760 Torr)  To see where this lies on the chart below convert 1 Torr to Bar by dividing by 750.1 So 0.0017/750.1 = 0.00000266 or about 2.7 x $10^{-5}$ Bar. The [chart](https://guide.leybold.com/en/pages/gas-flow) is in mBar so this falls into what would be considered a fine vacuum range, or about as good as a mechanical pump can hope to get.  For many purposes that is good enough, but for a lot of our modern technology for example depositing semiconductors thin films you can get better vacuums using more specialized pumps. In the lab it is now relatively easy to get vacuums in the $10^{-5}$ $10^{-8}$ Torr range, but it still takes effort to get $10^{-10} Torr range.

[image: https://guide.leybold.com/en/pages/gas-flow]

Since the Conversions can be confusing here is another vacuum pump vendors [chart](https://www.airtechusa.com/vacuum-pumps/).
[image: https://www.airtechusa.com/vacuum-pumps/]